# UITableView is slow

Tags: uitableview

I have a `view` which I dragged a `UITableView` in it, and 2 `UIImageView`s (the 1st one to show a background image and the second one is just showing a very small title at the top of the view with an image).
They're all set to `weak` properties. The tableView has 495 rows and an image loads into each cell.
Here's the code for configuring a cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }    

    int cellNumber = indexPath.row + 1;
    NSString *cellImage1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"c%i.png", cellNumber];
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:cellImage1];

    [cell.imageView setImage:theImage];


    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

    return cell;
}
```

I use `segue`s, so I don't need the delegate method. (which not relevant to this question either).
The thing is, the scrolling is smooth; BUT if I scroll *TOO FAST* then it gets slow and probably causes the app to crash. The png images loaded into cells are not big sizes, each one is around 5KB. It seems the the dequeueing job is not done efficiently; cuz it gets slow, shows a memory warning message and then the crash happens.
Anything I can do about it? (there's nothing else in the view)

UPDATE: I've also tried removing this part of code:

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

no use!

Comment: // the fast scrolling doesn't make iPod app slow! and it has both texts and images in it either. and this only happens on the device. Of course with the simulator, there's not a single problem and it's VERY smooth.

Comment: Have you considered moving the bgColorView creation logic into `if (cell = nil)` block? Otherwise, you're going to be creating that view every single time a cell is to be displayed...

Comment: I have even removed that part. it's still the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIImage imageNamed` caches your images and never frees the memory which is probably the cause of your memory warnings and crash. When dealing with large number of images it usually a good idea to load your images in some other way, such as `imageWithContentsOfFile` or `imageWithData`.

Comment: that's absolutely right. the memory usage is ok now and doesn't get increased! BUT the tableView is still a little slow on FAST SCROLLING.

Comment: UIImage imageNamed no longer caches and never frees the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try releasing the image after the `setImage` command. Does this help?

Comment: I'm using ARC, so it probably won't even allow me to do this.